# JQuery - Filtering data attributes with multiple filters of different inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, filter

I am working on a project where by I want to use JQuery in order to filter on data variables embedded onto divs that are on the page, its sort of like a showcase in which the users will be able to filter in various ways. So I have the following in my Div;

**HTML Result**

```
<div class="box col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2" 
    data-remote-name="BFT Mitto B RCB - 2 Button Remote" 
    data-remote-model="Mitto B RCB 2" 
    data-remote-freq="433" 
    data-remote-dips="" 
    data-remote-clone="" style="display: block;">
```

Data is pulled from an SQL table and hundreds of these are generated wit relevant data.

I got the following for working with the name alone, but I can't seem to figure out a way to have it filter on all the other inputs, as well as have the name and model looked at with this one input.

**JS/Query**

```
$('.box').hide().filter(function() {
    regExName = new RegExp($('#search-name').val().trim(), "ig");
    regExModel = new RegExp($('#search-name').val().trim(), "ig");
    return $(this).data("remote-name").match(regExName);
}).show();
```

This is then towards the top of the page and where the filtering criteria is. It currently contains 1 text input, 2 check boxes and 2 dropdowns. There will be many, many more filters when done.

```
  <div role="form" name="filters-form" id="filters-form">
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <input class="form-control" id="search-name" placeholder="Search for name or model..."/>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
  <div class="checkbox ">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dispwitch" value="dispwitch">
      Has Dip Switches?
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cloneable" value="cloneable">
      Cloneable?
    </label>
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
  Frequency:
  <select class="freq-dropdown form-control" id="frequency" style="width:100%;">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <?php foreach ($this->frequencies AS $frequency) {
      echo "<option value=\"" . $frequency->frequency . "\">" . $frequency->frequency . "</option>";
    }?>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
  Manufacturer:
  <select class="manufacturer-dropdown form-control" id="manufacturer" style="width:100%;">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <?php foreach ($this->manufacturers AS $manufacturer) {
      echo "<option value=\"" . $manufacturer->name . "\">" . $manufacturer->name . "</option>";
    }?>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Below is my current JS file as well as the output of 'data' which is an object i use to store states of filters.

```
$(function() {
$('.nav > li#remotes').toggleClass('active');

var data = { dips: null, cloneable: null, freq: null, manufacturer: null }; 

$("#filters-form").on("change keyup paste", function(){
    if ($('#dispwitch').is(':checked')) { data.dips = "1"; } else { data.dips = "0"; }
    if ($('#cloneable').is(':checked')) { data.cloneable = "1"; } else { data.cloneable = "0"; }
    data.freq = $('#frequency').val();
    data.manufacturer = $('#manufacturer').val();

    $('.box').hide().filter(function() {
        regExName = new RegExp($('#search-name').val().trim(), "ig");
        regExModel = new RegExp($('#search-name').val().trim(), "ig");
        return $(this).data("remote-name").match(regExName); 
        //I took out the previous answers changes, this currently works filtering via name.
    }).show();
    console.log(data);
});
```

});

EDIT2:
Another thing of note is some of the values are true/false/null so that needs to be accounted for in the filters. For example I got the check box filters semi-working with the following;

```
return $(this).data("remote-name").match(regExName) && $(this).data("remote-clone") == data.cloneable && $(this).data("remote-dips") == data.dips;
```

BUT... For those which have `[data-remote-dips=""]` as oppose to 1 or 0, once the filter is turned on or off a single time, the null valued are never shown until a refresh. Same issue with putting the dropdown to 'All' instead of a desired result, it then shows nothing on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after half a day of playing with JSFiddle I managed to get it working as I wanted, using RegExp as @David Johnson had menntioned.

https://jsfiddle.net/JokerDan/tqv0ybbz/2/

**Working HTML**

```
<div class="status"></div>
<div id="filterDiv">
  <input type="text" class="myInput" id="0"/>

  <select class="mySel" id="1">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
  </select>

  <select class="mySel" id="2">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="123">123</option>
    <option value="231">231</option>
    <option value="321">321</option>
  </select>

  <input type="checkbox" id="3"> Test Data :: 1 | 0 | NULL
</div>
<p class="p a 123" data-name="apple" data-a="a" data-b="123" data-test="1">Apple A 123 1</p>
<p class="p b 123" data-name="banana" data-a="b" data-b="123" data-test="0">Banana B 123 0</p>
<p class="p c 321" data-name="cherry" data-a="c" data-b="321" data-test="">Cherry C 321 X</p>
<p class="p a 321" data-name="date" data-a="a" data-b="321" data-test=""> Date A 321 X</p>
<p class="p a 123" data-name="elderberry" data-a="a" data-b="123" data-test="1">Elderberry A 123 1</p>
<p class="p c 231" data-name="fig" data-a="c" data-b="231" data-test="1">Fig C 231 1</p>
```

**Working JS**

```
$('#filterDiv').on("change keyup", function() {
  chkBox = { datatest: null };

  if ($('#3').is(':checked')) { chkBox.datatest = "1"; } else { chkBox.datatest = ""; }

  $("p").hide().filter(function() {
    var rtnData = "";

    regExName   = new RegExp($('#0').val().trim(), "ig");
    regExA          = new RegExp($('#1').val().trim(), "ig");
    regExB          = new RegExp($('#2').val().trim(), "ig");
    regExTest       = new RegExp(chkBox.datatest, "ig")

    rtnData = (
      $(this).attr("data-name").match(regExName) && 
      $(this).attr("data-a").match(regExA) && 
      $(this).attr("data-b").match(regExB) &&
      $(this).attr("data-test").match(regExTest)
    );

    //console.log(rtnData);
    return rtnData;
  }).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just need to extend the condition like this:

```
freq = new RegExp($('#frequency').val().trim(), "ig"); 
dips= new RegExp($('#dispwitch').val().trim(), "ig");
clone= new RegExp($('#cloneable').val().trim(), "ig");

return $(this).data("remote-name").match(regExName) || $(this).data("remote-freq").match(freq) || $(this).data("remote-dips").match(dips) || $(this).data("remote-clone").match(clone)
```

Comment: Does not seem to be working, the text filter now doesn't filter at all and instead just hides all, the selectable filters have no effect.

Console shows type error of: TypeError: $(...).data(...).match is not a function // 

...("remote-name").match(regExName) || $(this).data("remote-freq").match(freq) || $...

// Error shows on $(this).data("remote-freq").