# jQuery multiple filter data attributes

Tags: jquery

i need to filter data attribute using jQuery. 
First i want to filter via selectbox and then filter with checkbox. All i want is when i checked both textbox, data will display all. But now, it only show the first data checkbox. Please see fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/legazy7891/t9krfjpy/4/

At if condition i've tried :

```
if ($('.3').is(':checked')) { chkBox.datatest = "1"; } 
 else if ($('.4').is(':checked')) { chkBox.datatest = "6"; } 
 else if ($('.3').is(':checked') && $('.4').is(':checked')) { chkBox.datatest = ""; } 
 else { chkBox.datatest = ""; }
```

But it doesn't work.

Reference : [JQuery - Filtering data attributes with multiple filters of different inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153667/jquery-filtering-data-attributes-with-multiple-filters-of-different-inputs)

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the order of the condition. When you select both check box, the first condition will get satisfy `$('.3').is(':checked')` and `chBox.dataset` will get set to 1. It won't go to third condition.

Try following

```
if ($('.3').is(':checked') && $('.4').is(':checked')) {
   chkBox.datatest = "";
} else if ($('.3').is(':checked')) {
   chkBox.datatest = "1";
} else if ($('.4').is(':checked')) {
   chkBox.datatest = "6";
} else {
   chkBox.datatest = "";
}
```

Comment: How about if i have more than 2 checkboxes? i think i need better method instead of add condition in every single checkbox